# Consumir objeto Json anidado dentro de otro objeto usando Volley

Tags: android, json, volley

Estimados gusto en saludarlos, estoy tratando de consumir un objeto `Json` a través de `Volley` usando `Android`, sin embargo solo consigo consumir una parte del `Json`. Soy nuevo en esto , espero me puedan ayudar,Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Cristian, acostumbra agregar el código como texto no como imagen, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Los datos que pudiste obtener se encuentran dentro de un objeto json pero los datos que señalas también se encuentran dentro de un objeto llamado "contact":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtén el objeto "contact" y posteriormente sus propiedades:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectContact = jsonObject.getJSONObject("contact");

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Respuesta"+
jsonObject.getString("id") + " " +
jsonObject.getString("name") + " " +
jsonObject.getString("email") + " " +
jsonObject.getString("gender") + " " +
jsonObjectContact.getString("mobile") + " " +
jsonObjectContact.getString("home") + " " +
jsonObjectContact.getString("office"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder con:

```
JSONObject contactJObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("contact");
System.out.println(contactObject.getString("mobile"));
```